# Two variable declaration with same namespace and type shows 'Redefination of <VARIABLE_NAME>'

Tags: ios, objective-c

**My code is following:**

```
    /**************************/

    NSMutableArray *aa = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    aa = nil;

    NSMutableArray *aa = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   /***************************/
```

It shows an error,

> "Redefinition of aa".

Why this error is occurred? Please explain in detail.

Comment: EPIC Question I must say

Comment: @AnkitSachan lol. One of those questions that can leave you speechless.

Comment: It is a good question.HE just want to get clarification regarding the resue of variable by setting it to nil.

Answer (score 7):

Setting a defined variable to `nil` does **not** "undefine" the variable

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
NSMutableArray *aa = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

aa = nil;

aa = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: I have understood whatever you have said. But my question is , why we will get this error, because before second time initialization I am setting the previous intialized variable to nil?

Comment: You declared same variable with same name twice - that's th eproblem